# nHibernate ICriteria Join Condition

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I am trying to use ICriteria to create a query that has a join
condition. The SQL I am trying to generate should look like this

```
SELECT c.ClientID
FROM Client c
LEFT OUTER JOIN ClientContact t on c.ClientID = t.ClientID AND
t.ContactType = 'Email'
```

If I use a criteria like

```
m_ClientRepository.QueryAlias("client")
     .CreateCriteria("client.Contacts", "c", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
     .Add(Restrictions.Eq("c.ContactType", ContactType.Email));
```

It will generate the sql below which I don't want.

```
SELECT c.ClientID
FROM Client c
LEFT OUTER JOIN ClientContact t on c.ClientID = t.ClientID
WHERE t.ContactType = 'Email'
```

Is there anyway to do this with ICriteria or HQL if ICriteria is not possible ?

Edit: I have discovered nHibernate 2.1 (which I am using) does now [allow this](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/05/17/nhibernate-2-1-0-hql-with-clause.aspx). Not sure about ICriteria though, this is my preference.

Comment: I am looking for exactly the same thing in Criteria. We need the with expression.

Comment: Not being much of an sql guy but why would you want the first option over the second, do they not give the same results?

Comment: Hi Colin, they do not give the same results.

Comment: @Colin they would be the same with `INNER JOIN` (or just `JOIN`, which is the same). With `LEFT OUTER` (or `LEFT`), the results could differ.

Comment: man, did you forget to accept some answer, or neither is acceptable?

Comment: Michael, None of these answers really work. But I will post the correct solution I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the only way to do this with NHibernate 3 and before is via filters like in [this example](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/10/13/nhibernate-icriteria-and-filters/)

In NHibernate 3.1 this is now supported in a better way, https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2190

Comment: The link is dead unfortunately :/
Edit: Is it this one? https://www.codewrecks.com/post/old/2009/10/nhibernate-icriteria-and-filters/

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't do this. The left outer join let's NH load clients anyway, the filter for E-Mail contacts would load only E-Mail contacts ... until it initializes the contact collection and loads everything anyway.

If it would load only E-Mail contacts, it would end up in incomplete objects in memory. This is usually not a good idea, particularly when you are also changing data in the same transaction.

In your situation I would try to load EMail contacts directly and navigate from the contact to the customer.

```
session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Contact))
     .Add(Restrictions.Eq("c.ContactType", ContactType.Email));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you won't find a way to form correct `join`, you can make a simple trick: just make your restriction be `WHERE t.ContactType = 'Email' OR t.ClientID IS NULL` - hopefully, it is possible with NHibernate.

Comment: You'll need to change the join to an inner join if you use this workaround.

Comment: @Jamie No. It is `LEFT JOIN` now and it is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could use IQuery in conjunction with ISQLQuery. That's not a Criteria mechanism, but it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
from s in Session.Linq<Client> left join cc in c.Contacts
        on
        new { c.ClientID , cc.ClientID }
        equals
         new { cc.ContactType, "Email" }
        select c.ClientId;
```

Hope this works if you are using Nhibernate 2